# Hide a parent node in TreeView if there are no child nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a TreeView on my .aspx page. I want to hide those parent node of a treeview when there are no child nodes.

Comment: give your code how you are populating your treeview

Comment: @neha- I am populating tree by fetching require values from database.

Answer (score 1):

See this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2009/06/09/hide-a-parent-node-in-treeview-if-there-is-no-childnodes.aspx)

```
protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapNode node = (SiteMapNode)e.Node.DataItem;
    if(node.HasChildNodes ==false && e.Node.Depth ==1)
    {
        TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Remove(e.Node);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have sitemap for a treeview.